# Category page next page wordpress doesnt work

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi im having problems with my post category list next page, when i clicknext it goes to a sample page.

my personalize permalink is: /%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/

my site: http://hgps.org.do/prevencion_salud/

```
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php echo avada_render_rich_snippets_for_pages(); ?>
        <?php if( ! post_password_required($post->ID) ): // 1 ?>
        <?php global $smof_data; if(!$smof_data['featured_images_pages'] ): // 2 ?>
        <?php
        if( avada_number_of_featured_images() > 0 || get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pyre_video', true ) ): // 3
        ?>
        <div class="fusion-flexslider flexslider post-slideshow">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video', true)): ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="full-video">
                        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_video', true); ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pyre_show_first_featured_image', true ) != 'yes' ): ?>
                <?php $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); ?>
                <?php $full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); ?>
                <?php $attachment_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata(get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $full_image[0]; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery<?php the_ID(); ?>]" title="<?php echo get_post_field('post_excerpt', get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>" data-title="<?php echo get_post_field('post_title', get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>" data-caption="<?php echo get_post_field('post_excerpt', get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $attachment_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>" /></a>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                $i = 2;
                while($i <= $smof_data['posts_slideshow_number']):
                $attachment_new_id = kd_mfi_get_featured_image_id('featured-image-'.$i, 'page');
                if($attachment_new_id):
                ?>
                <?php $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_new_id, 'full'); ?>
                <?php $full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_new_id, 'full'); ?>
                <?php $attachment_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_new_id); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $full_image[0]; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery<?php the_ID(); ?>]" title="<?php echo get_post_field('post_excerpt', $attachment_new_id); ?>" data-title="<?php echo get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_new_id ); ?>" data-caption="<?php echo get_post_field('post_excerpt', $attachment_new_id ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $attachment_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta($attachment_new_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>" /></a>
                </li>
                <?php endif; $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: is your pagination and prev and next links placed outside the loop?